# Inconsistent import behavior between ts-node and jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-jest

I have a typescript project with the following libraries: winston 2.4.7, ts-node 10.9.1, and jest 29.5.0

In my package json I have `"type": "module",`

In some folder I do:

```
import winston from 'winston'

...
winston.loggers.add(...
```

Now, if I run the project with ts-node: `node --loader ts-node/esm src/main.ts`, it works as expected.

However, if I run the jest tests `yarn jest` it fails because "winston.loggers" is undefined.

If I happen to change the import to `import * as winston from 'winston'`, then jest succeeds but ts-node fails.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the following preset:

```
preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts'
```

This one worked:

```
preset: 'ts-jest'
```